# Convert multiline string of numbers to double array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string matrix

```
stringMatrix = `
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
`
```

And I want to convert it to a double array: `[[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]]`; what the js-y way of doing that?

I've tried `matrix = values[0].trim().split('\n');`, but that will only do the outer layer: `["1 0 0", "0 1 0", "0 0 0"]`; I could do a for-loop, but I was wondering if there was a way with lambda expressions/fat arrows?

//vanilla js

Comment: `stringMatrix.trim().split("\n").map(e => e.split(" "));`

Comment: @ASDFGerte `stringMatrix.trim().split("\n").map(e => e.split(" ").map(number));`

Comment: ah yes, convert to number. But you don't need another `map`, just use `Number(e.split(" "))` or the imho not well readable `+e.split(" ")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just splitting and mapping it would be the easies

```js
var stringMatrix = `
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
`

var res = stringMatrix.trim().split("\n").map( x => x.split(/\s+/).map(Number))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer..IMHO..Question @adeneo: Can you explain what's going on with the regex sequence inside the `split()` method? e.g, `split(/\s+/)`?  I know the `\s` is for a space, but what do the initial and trailing `/`'s signify?

Comment: Just a quick followup: This multi-line string (spaces included only to denote line breaks): 
    `3,
   11 2 4,
   4 5 6,
   10 8 -12,` (3, 11.., 4.., 10.., each a unique line) yields this matrix: `[ [ 3 ], [ 0, 11, 2, 4 ], [ 0, 4, 5, 6 ], [ 0, 10, 8, -12 ] ]`. Notice the `0` digit where there should be none? How might the regex string be adjusted to remove this additional 0?

Comment: Nevermind my friend, I ended up figuring out my issue...the reason I was getting 0's was that I had extra `"  "` (spaces) in my multi-line literal string... :)

Answer (score 0):

this would give you an number array as an output, using split and map

```js
stringMatrix = `
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
`;
let result = [];
stringMatrix = stringMatrix.trim().split('\n').map(function(element){
    let ret = [];

    for(let digit of element.match(/\d/g)){
        ret.push(parseInt(digit));
    }
    return ret;
});


console.log(stringMatrix);
```